# How do I plot date and time in charts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made this software which binds the chart with gridview. On its x-axis, I'm plotting date-time and on y-axis, I have values in double datatype. I am facing problem in getting x-axis points as it is just plotting against date and not considering the time. Here is the grid view:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series["LDA"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart1.DataSource = dt2;
        chart1.Series["LDA"].XValueMember = "Date";
        chart1.Series["LDA"].YValueMembers = "Difference";
        //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0.01;
        chart1.DataBind();
    }
```

And here is the graph:

[image]

Please also tell how to get the chart to show the plotted values separately. The grid view has numerous values so the chart here is showing all the values accumulated in one place. I want it to use a horizontal scroll bar and show significantly the values at each time. Please help...

Comment: try looking at the official samples
answer is there
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Answer (score 0):

you can use google chart

[google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

its easiest way to do chart

[tutorials](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-beautiful-data-visualisations-svg-google-charts-api)